# Is it possible to split arguments in to value in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
function one(){
    two(arguments)
}

function two(a, b){
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}

one('a', 'b');
```

Comment: If you always only want to pass two arguments: `two(arguments[0], arguments[1])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
function one(){
    two.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments))
}
```

Some older engines insist upon receiving an array as the second parameter to `apply()`. Unfortunately, [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is an *array-like object*. That's to say, it's not truly an array but it has a `length` property and numeric indices in addition to `callee` and `caller` properties. So, we call `Array.slice()` in order to get a plain array to pass to `apply()`.

That said, V8 (used by node.js) should be fine without such translation:

```
function one(){
    two.apply(null, arguments)
}
```

That was my fault, I missed the [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) tag.

Comment: You might also explain why you're using the `.slice()`.

Answer (score 3):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/xNFWk/)***

You are looking for [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). The apply syntax will allow you to pass an array of values as the arguments to a function.

```
function one(){
 two.apply(this, arguments);
}

function two(a, b){
 console.log(a);
 console.log(b);
}

one('a', 'b');
```